# Why I am getting different 95% confidence interval for some studies in meta-analysis in "meta" package in r?

Tags: r, meta, confidence-interval

I am trying to do a meta-analysis using hazard ratio, lower and upper 95% confidence interval but for example CARDIa study, obtained upper and lower 95%CI ([2.1560; 9.9858]) were different than the original values (1.33-6.16) and I do not know how to get the exact numbers.

**Any advice will be greatly appreciated.**

**Used code:**

```
library(meta);library(metafor)

data<-read.table(text="studlab  HR  LCI UCI
Blazek  1.78    0.84    3.76
PRECOMBAT   1.20    0.37    3.93
LE.MANS 1.14    0.3 4.25
NOBLE   2.99    1.66    5.39
MASS-II 2.90    1.39    6.01
CARDIa  4.64    1.33    6.16
BEST    2.75    1.16    6.54
", header=T, sep="")

metagen(log(HR), lower = log(LCI), upper = log(UCI),
        studlab = studlab,data=data, sm = "HR")
```

**Obtained results**

````
             HR           95%-CI   %W(fixed) %W(random)
Blazek    1.7800 [0.8413; 3.7659]      16.4       16.5
PRECOMBAT 1.2000 [0.3682; 3.9109]       6.6        7.1
LE.MANS   1.1400 [0.3029; 4.2908]       5.2        5.7
NOBLE     2.9900 [1.6593; 5.3878]      26.6       25.0
MASS-II   2.9000 [1.3947; 6.0301]      17.2       17.2
CARDIa    4.6400 [2.1560; 9.9858]      15.7       15.8
BEST      2.7500 [1.1582; 6.5297]      12.3       12.7

Number of studies combined: k = 7

                         HR           95%-CI    z  p-value
Fixed effect model   2.5928 [1.9141; 3.5122] 6.15 < 0.0001
Random effects model 2.5695 [1.8611; 3.5477] 5.73 < 0.0001

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.0181 [0.0000; 0.9384]; tau = 0.1347 [0.0000; 0.9687];
 I^2 = 9.4% [0.0%; 73.6%]; H = 1.05 [1.00; 1.94]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f. p-value
 6.63    6  0.3569

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- DerSimonian-Laird estimator for tau^2
- Jackson method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "exact numbers"?

Comment: @Edward I mentioned that in my question. Instead of getting same upper and lower confidence intervals as in the published study, I am getting different numbers. Thx for your interest.

Comment: That's because the function needs to estimate the standard errors from the confidence intervals and then it calculates the confidence intervals from the standard errors.

Comment: @Edward: Thx for your reply.  I see what you're saying but wondering if there is a way to adjust that . I tried```hakn=gs("hakn")``` but no difference could be seen. Any way to fix that?. Thx again. Upvoted!

Comment: Maybe the `approx.seTE` argument can help. But i wonder if the original CI for the CARDIa study is correct.

Comment: @Edward: Thx for your suggestions. I tried it but it's not solved yet. Thx

Comment: This may be a better question for [stats.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CI output matches the original CI to 2 decimal places in all studies except for CARDIa, which I think has been incorrectly entered (forgive me if I'm wrong but I can't see any other explanation).

You can see this by calculating the standard errors manually and then recalculating the confidence intervals, much like the `metagen` function does.

```
library(meta)

se <- meta:::TE.seTE.ci(log(data$LCI), log(data$UCI))$seTE; se
#[1] 0.3823469 0.6027896 0.6762603 0.3004463 0.3735071 0.3910526 0.4412115

data$lower <- round(exp(ci(TE=log(data$HR), seTE=se)$lower), 3)
data$upper <- round(exp(ci(TE=log(data$HR), seTE=se)$upper), 3)

data
    studlab   HR  LCI  UCI lower upper
1    Blazek 1.78 0.84 3.76 0.841 3.766  # 
2 PRECOMBAT 1.20 0.37 3.93 0.368 3.911  # 
3   LE.MANS 1.14 0.30 4.25 0.303 4.291  # 
4     NOBLE 2.99 1.66 5.39 1.659 5.388  # 
5   MASS-II 2.90 1.39 6.01 1.395 6.030  # 
6    CARDIa 4.64 1.33 6.16 2.156 9.986  # <- this one is incorrect. 
7      BEST 2.75 1.16 6.54 1.158 6.530  #
```

The correct 95% CI for CARDIa should be around (2.16 - 9.99). I would verify that you have typed the values correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I reviewed the published article myself and realized that HR was 4.64 (1.33 -16.16) instead of (4.64 1.33 - 6.16) . Thx a lot. Answer accepted and Upvoted!.

Comment: I tried this study ```data<-read.table(text="studlab HR LCI UCI
Blazek et al. 0.98 0.51 1.35
", header=T, sep="\t")``` It gives me off values of ```0.9800 [0.6023; 1.5944]```  Any of your precious input?

Comment: Again, I think the 95% CI is incorrect. If you know the standard error of the estimate, you can use that in the `metagen` function. Suppose it is 0.33. The function will return a 95% CI of 0.51 - 1.87. The lower CI matches but the upper CI doesn't match your input of 1.35. So again, check your source. If it is correct, then the authors or the editor of the journal article must have made an error. It happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to contact them. Appreciate your input. Upvoted!